# IBAction not registering button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, ibaction

I want the code in `- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender` to run when I click my next button, however clicking it doesn't seem to register.

I made sure the `nextButton` was connected to the parent controller (`SearchViewController`), and I have two segues leading to the two secondary view controllers.

The view controller it segues to depends on the value returned by the function.

I'm thinking that the problem is either in how I structured the function, or how I laid out the segues.

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemSearch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextButton;

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {
        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            NSLog(@"The result is '%@'", result);

                                            if ([result intValue] == 1) {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue" sender:self];
                                            } else {
                                                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowCriteriaSegue" sender:self];
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check your outlets, check your preconditions, then check that you didn't set a breakpoint inside that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I can think of is that while the button maybe connected to searchViewController, - (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender may not be assigned to the button. 
Try this in searchViewController: 
First, in its header file, add nextButtonOutlet as an IBOutlet. Then in the .m file, write

```
[self.nextButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

See if this works.

Edit: write that line of code in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: So you're saying to ctrl drag the next button to the .h file, name it nextButtonOutlet, in addition to having the nextButton IBOutlet in the .m file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**Step 1:** Create `IBOutlet` for button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.nextButtonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
}
```

**Step 2:** Button Action

```
- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Button Clicked");
    //-- Your code implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect the segue from the button itself and make the connection between the two ViewControllers. Also, give the segue itself an identifier.